# HTML, CSS div and img element placement

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a school assignment which I'm working on. Its a survey with data visualisation, which supports editing deleting and adding questions. For the visualisation I use pie charts, which are positioned under each other in a single image.

I would like to place DIV elements under each other, and place the long image beside these div elements as shown on the picture below:

[image: Picture].

There can be a variable number of divs, and the height of the image is variable too. How do I achieve this?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can achieve this with flexboxes. Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_flexbox.asp)(link) and the example provided near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Bootstrap, it's an easy form to make an structure, using CSS and Javascript, very flexible, check the examples at for making such as design https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/